# Android - CardView doesn't show up on RecyclerView connected to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm building a `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment`, which brings in data from **Firebase** database and suppose to show them on a `CardView`. I wrote all the code as shown below but all that appears upon running is an empty `RecyclerView` Fragment with the method `getItemCount()` returning always 0.

**card_item.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primaryText"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subText"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rateValue"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subText"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F1F1F1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/placesRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**PlacesModel.java**

```
public class PlaceModel {
private String mPrimaryText, mSubText, mRateValue;

public PlaceModel() {
}

public PlaceModel(String mCardImage, String mPrimaryText,
                  String mSubText, String mRateValue) {
    //this.mCardImageURL = mCardImage;
    this.mPrimaryText = mPrimaryText;
    this.mSubText = mSubText;
    this.mRateValue = mRateValue;

}

 public void setmPrimaryText(String mPrimaryText) {
    this.mPrimaryText = mPrimaryText;
}

public void setmSubText(String mSubText) {
    this.mSubText = mSubText;
}

public void setmRateValue(String mRateValue) {
    this.mRateValue = mRateValue;
}


public String getmPrimaryText() {
    return mPrimaryText;
}

public String getmSubText() {
    return mSubText;
}

public String getmRateValue() {
    return mRateValue;
}}
```

**PlacesAdapter.java**

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAdapter.PlacesViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<PlaceModel> cardContents;
private Context context;

public PlacesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PlaceModel> cardContents) {
    this.cardContents = cardContents;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public PlacesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    return new PlacesViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlacesViewHolder holder, int position) {

    PlaceModel place = cardContents.get(position);
    holder.primaryText.setText(place.getmPrimaryText());
    holder.subText.setText(place.getmSubText());
    holder.rateValue.setText(place.getmRateValue());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cardContents.size();
}

public class PlacesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;
    public TextView primaryText, subText, rateValue;


    public PlacesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        primaryText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.primaryText);
        subText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subText);
        rateValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rateValue);

    }

}}
```

**FirebaseConnector.java**

```
  public class FirebaseConnector {
DatabaseReference db;
PlaceModel placeModel = new PlaceModel();
ArrayList<PlaceModel> cardContent = new ArrayList<>();


public FirebaseConnector(DatabaseReference db) {
    this.db = db;

}

public ArrayList<PlaceModel> retrieve() {

    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return cardContent;
}

private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    cardContent.clear(); //clear card content from last usage

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        placeModel = ds.child("Place Model").getValue(PlaceModel.class);
        cardContent.add(placeModel);
     }

 }}
```

**ProfileFragment.java**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private RecyclerView placesRecycler;
private PlacesAdapter placesAdapter;
private FirebaseConnector connector;
private DatabaseReference ref;


// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;


public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static ProfileFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    //Initialize Database..
    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    connector = new FirebaseConnector(ref);

    //Initialize RecyclerView
    placesRecycler = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.placesRecycler);
    placesRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    //Adapter
    placesAdapter = new PlacesAdapter(this.getActivity(), connector.retrieve());
    placesRecycler.setAdapter(placesAdapter);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "We have "+placesAdapter.getItemCount()+" cards", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
    }
}

public void updateUI() {

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
    }

}}
```

**Database trial structure**
[Database trial structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Qg1.png)

Comment: can you post your firebase structure here?

Comment: `placeModel = ds.child("Place Model").getValue(PlaceModel.class);` what is `Place space Model` child here

Comment: @akhilesh0707 Screeenshot added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that retrieve method will return empty array list because it won't wait for the listener to finish (note that listener works in another thread)

You may make move the listener to the profile fragment and every time you update the ArrayList write

```
placesRecycler.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Comment: Thanks A lot.That helped me to figure out the dilemma and solve it. I was missing some vital information about Datasnapshot. Indeed i found out that cardContent List would be null everytime called by fragment (main) thread because it's filled from Firebase via different thread which needed to be synchronized with the main thread by using  notifydatasetchanged(); . Noting that moving the listener to the fragment itself has nothing to do with the problem. It's all about threads synchronization.

Comment: Great that you solved the problem , good luck in your project.